# jQuery - find another child element value of same parent row

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have following **HTML** which render on page dynamically multiples times as per user needs. i just want to find `input:volume` from `input:length` so i can calculate each row volume.

> simple concept (from **one child** to get **another child** element using parent **row** )
>
> > from child --> parent  --> child

```
<div class="row" id="product-row-1">
    <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
        <label for="product-qty-1"><span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        <input type="number" min="1" id="product-qty-1" name="quantity-1" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
        <label for="product-weight-1"><span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        <input type="number" min="0" step="0.01" id="product-weight-1" name="product-weight-1" class="form-control" max="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 form-group dimensions">
        <label for="product-dimensions-length-1"><span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4"><input type="number" min="0" class="form-control dimensionsinfo" max="" step="0.01" id="product-dimensions-length-1" name="product-dimensions-length-1"></div>
        <div class="col-4"><input type="number" min="0" class="form-control dimensionsinfo" max="" step="0.01"  id="product-dimensions-width-1" name="product-dimensions-width-1"></div>
        <div class="col-4"><input type="number" min="0" class="form-control dimensionsinfo" max="" step="0.01" id="product-dimensions-height-1" name="product-dimensions-height-1"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
        <label for="product-volume-1"><span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        <input type="number" id="product-volume-1" step="0.01" name="volume-1" min="0" max="" class="form-control volumeinfo">
    </div>
</div>
```

Right now i got parent **row** using

`$('.dimensionsinfo').closest(".row") //parent row i got`

But now i want to *child* `volumeinfo` element's value using that *parent* **row**.  so i tried following things but not working.

> `$('.dimensionsinfo').closest(".row").find('.volumeinfo').val() //not working`

i cannot use `product-row-1` because each row id added dynamically by number
how can i access same row element on this situation?

Comment: Can you describe better what your expectation is? Can you also create a JSFiddle?

Comment: sure. let me add those thing on JSFiddle.

Comment: try like this --> `$('.dimensionsinfo').closest('.dimensions').closest('.row').find('.volumeinfo').val()`

Comment: Thank you. Please let me know when you are done.

Comment: @Swati thank you so much. it's working great..!!

Comment: @LajosArpad   https://jsfiddle.net/pd6bcjtx/1/ added here.

Comment: Thank you for the Fiddle. It seems that the problem is already solved there, is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

When you write `$('.dimensionsinfo').closest(".row")` , you will not get the row with `id="product-row-1"`. What you will actually get is the closest element with `class="row"`

To select the desired common parent row, a different class should be added to it

```
<div class="row parent-row" id="product-row-1">
```

Now, to select that common row

`$('.dimensionsinfo').closest(".parent-row");`

And to find the value of `input` element with `class="volumeinfo"`

`$('.dimensionsinfo').closest(".parent-row").find('.volumeinfo').val();`

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are getting closest row which is just a parent of dimensionsinfo not the whole row's parent so you are getting undefined, there are many ways we can achieve that:

Please see below couple of ways:

```
console.log($('.dimensionsinfo').parents("#product-row-1").find('.volumeinfo').val());

console.log($('.dimensionsinfo').closest("#product-row-1").find('.volumeinfo').val());

console.log($('.dimensionsinfo').closest(".dimensions").next().find('.volumeinfo').val());
```

Jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/pd6bcjtx/1/

Comment: Thanks for answer the last solution great for me because `#product-row-1` will not work in my case. because it added dynamically in code. so using class it would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

To access siblings using jQuery, you require two method parents and find.

```
let parent=$(".dimensionsinfo').parent(); //access parent
let sibling=$(parent).find(".volumeinfo"); //find children 
let val=$(sibling).val(); //get child value
```